# Combine each element of a string with the second string

Tags: javascript, php

I have 2 strings

```
[a,b,c]  //there could be any number of items in these 2 strings
[x,y,z]
```

I want an output like this

```
a[x,y,z]
b[x,y,z]
c[x,y,z]
```

Not quite able to get the logic to get the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get as an array use **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**

```js
var s1 = '[a,b,c]',
  s2 = '[x,y,z]';
console.log(
  s1
  .slice(1, -1) // remove the `[` and `]`
  .split(',') // split based on `,`
  .map(function(a) { // iterate and generate array
    return a + s2;
  })
)
```

---

To get as a string use **[`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)**

```js
var s1 = '[a,b,c]',
  s2 = '[x,y,z]';
console.log(
  s1
  .slice(1, -1) // remove `[` and `]`
  .split(',') // split based on `,`
  .reduce(function(a, b) { // iterate and generate string
    return a + (a.length ? '\n' : ' ') + b + s2;
  }, '')
)
```

Comment: what if there are 'n' number of items in those strings

Comment: @user4381753 : it will wok with any number of strings

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$s1 = '[a,b,c]';
$s2 = '[x,y,z]';

$items = explode(',', trim($s1, '[]'));
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo($item . $s2 . "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `String.slice` and `String.replace` functions:

```
var keys = '[a,b,c,d,e]', values = '[x,y,z]',
    output = keys.slice(1, -1).replace(/([a-z]),?/g, function(m, p1){
        return p1 + values + "\n";
    });

console.log(output);
```

The output:

```
a[x,y,z]
b[x,y,z]
c[x,y,z]
d[x,y,z]
e[x,y,z]
```